# Refinement and inheritance in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, stl, iterator

what is refinement in c++?

while reading c++ primer plus i came across following statement:

> in terms of the C++ language, this particular bidirectional iterator,
>   being a built-in type, couldn’t be derived from a class. Conceptually,
>   however, it does inherit. Some STL literature uses the term refinement
>   to indicate this conceptual inheritance. Thus, a bidirectional
>   iterator is a refinement of the forward iterator concept

how are inheritance and refinement related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refinement means something like "It has the same attributes (or features, or requirements), plus more."

If the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is followed, inheritance is usually refinement, because you can do all the base class things with a derived instance, and a derived instance satisfies all the base requirements.

Refinement does not have to be implemented using inheritance.  This is partly due to C++ supporting static polymorphism, e.g. templates.  A bidirectional iterator is a refinement of a forward iterator even if the former does not inherit from the latter, so long as programs can use a bidirectional iterator wherever a forward iterator is required.  Functions which take iterators usually take them as template types, so all that matters is that they implement a known set of methods (e.g. increment and dereference for forward iterators, plus decrement for bidirectional).